# EXCEL highlight corresponding rows and columns in other tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 3 tables in the same sheet as follows:

[image]

I need to highlight corresponding rows and columns in other 2 tables.
What I can do now is to highlight rows and columns, but can not figure out how to highlight corresponding columns in other tables. For example, if I select Melon or one of its values in Table 1, then get same selection in other 2 tables, and vice versa.

I have used this formula in conditional formatting --> Use a formula to determine which cells to format:

```
=OR(CELL("col")=COLUMN();CELL("row")=ROW())
```

I can also use this VBA code to update automatically (otherwise press F9) to update highlight.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

Here's my result for now:
[image]

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you will need VBA to make all tables sensitive to the active cell alone. You could create a drop down list with your items to select from and then create your rules around that cells value. That will only help you highlight the correct rows though.

Comment: Also, is `Table1` the only table where the selection matters? If you select *Lime* in `Table2` do you also want `Lime` to be highlighted in `Table2` and `Table3`? If so, that requires more work

Comment: yes, when I select lime in first table, same row and column should be selected in other 2 tables.

Comment: then only that tables rows and columns will be highlighted. But in my case, all 3 tables have same data in description field. They are just found in different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following:

[image]

The conditional formatting rule for `I3:O14`:

```
=OR(ROW()-2=MATCH(INDEX($B:$B,CELL("row")),$J$3:$J$14,0),CELL("col")=COLUMN()-8)
```

Obviously you can apply the same logic to the other table. Note, this is only sensitive to selections in table1

Comment: Hi! Yes, it works only on Table 1, but for other tables it doesn't work correctly.

Comment: As you can see it works fine for me @rocco

Comment: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/a29db84a69a265a905942e5cb87a5cba20201228181259/689ef8e87fdf42231523e1ff8a5c294720201228181319/f06e51